Trouble with Django Authentication: Instead of showing templates it show admin page
I'm currently learning Django authentication and have encountered an issue with customizing HTML templates. Instead of displaying my custom templates, Django redirects me to the admin dashboard.
For instance, when I modify LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL to logout and name in TemplateView to logout, I expect to see my custom logout page located at templates/registration/logout.html. However, Django continues to redirect me to the default admin dashboard logout page. But when i set both to customlogout then it directs me correctly.
Similarly, I face a problem with the "Forgotten your password?" button. When clicking on it, I anticipate being directed to templates/registration/password_reset_form.html, but instead, I'm redirected to the Django admin dashboard.
Below is my code setup:
settings.py:
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = "customlogout"

app urls.py:
from django.urls import path
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

urlpatterns = [
    path('', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='home.html'), name='home'), 
    path('logout/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='logout.html'), name='customlogout'), 
]

project urls.py:
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('account.urls')),
    path("accounts/", include("django.contrib.auth.urls")), 
]

Password reset template templates/registration/password_reset_form.html:
<h1>Password Reset</h1>
<p>Enter your email ID to reset the password</p>
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">Reset</button>
</form>

Edit
If I move my templates out of registration folder into templates folder, then the following work
 path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name='logout.html'), name='logout'),
    path('password-reset/', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(template_name='password_reset_form.html'), name='password_reset'),

But why its not working before

It should be template="registration/.." there should be full path.

Your templates are located at these locations:
templates/registration/logout.html
templates/registration/password_reset_form.html

Whereas you're not passing the correct location in urls.py
You should pass the correct location:
path('logout/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='registration/logout.html'), name='customlogout'), 
path('password-reset/', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(template_name='registration/password_reset_form.html'), name='password_reset'),


   path('password-reset/', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(template_name='registration/password_reset_form.html'), name='password_reset'), lead me to password reset on admin dashboard instead of custom page

Point 1

when I modify LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL to logout and name in TemplateView to logout, I expect to see my custom logout page located at templates/registration/logout.html.

In django by default template_name parameter is relative to templates folder. Since your logout.html file is located in templates/registration/logout.html directory, template_name should be:
path('logout/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='registration/logout.html'), name='customlogout'),

Otherwise, django will use its default logout.html template (which is what is happening in your case).

If I move my templates out of registration folder into templates folder, then the following work

That's because you are overriding django's default logout.html file.
Point 2
As for url route names, similar thing is happening here too.
Your custom name=logout url name is overlapping with django's default url name.
To prevent this, you should define app_name in your urls.py file
for example
app urls.py:
from django.urls import path
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

app_name = 'main_app' # or 'registration_app' or just 'app'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='home.html'), name='home'), 
    path('logout/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='logout.html'), name='logout'), 
]


and in your template files you should inclue app_name in your url tags:
some_html_page.html:
 <a class="logout-link" href="{% url 'main_app:logout' %}">
  logout
 </a>


After spending few hours, I found the issue in my code.
First i need to rename logout.html to logged_out.html. Ref here
Second I need to change the order of INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py and put my app on first position. ref here.
Now my updated code look like below
urls.py of app
urlpatterns = [
    path('', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='home.html'), name='home'), 
]

urls.py of project
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path("accounts/", include("account.urls")),
    path("accounts/", include("django.contrib.auth.urls")),
]

settings.py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'account.apps.AccountConfig',# put app here
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = "logout"


All default template name can be found here. Typo in the naming of html template file wont work.
